# What is this hinged tool with a box full of wicked grooves and teeth?

Tags: equipment, utensils

Recently, while cleaning out my mother's kitchen, we came across this tool:

[image]

When closed, it is about 8 inches long (the box at the end is maybe 2 inches by 2 inches by an inch or so).  The two sides come apart very easily.  The tool is quite light-weight, and seems to be made of aluminum.  Other than that, I have idea what it could be, and there seemed to be no identifying marks or branding.

Honestly, I would not be surprised to learn that it is not even a kitchen tool (my money is on Medieval torture device), but it came from one of the kitchen cabinets, so maybe it belongs there?

Comment: What’s the size of the compartment?  And are there holes in it?   (I don’t know what it is, but it might work as a citrus juicer)

Comment: Yeah, I'd say juicer if it has holes, nutcracker if it doesn't.

Comment: Incidentally, the idea of medieval torture devices was largely propaganda by people in the Victorian era as a way of making themselves look good. IIRC most of them were actually from the Early Modern period, if they existed at all.

Comment: @nick012000 Oh, indeed.  But "Medieval" torture device sounds much better in a sentence than "Early modern" or "Bush era" torture device.  And when making a joke, how it sounds in the ear matters, I think.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an ice crusher.

[image: Ice crusher]

You put some cubes (or use your ice pick to cut a hunk off from a large block), put it in the compartment, and squeeze it closed. Those gnarly bumps and teeth will crush the ice.

I would personally consider it more "home bar equipment" for crushing ice for cocktails, though that's certainly not the only use. As mentioned in the comments, it probably doubles as a decent nutcracker, though that's not it's intended purpose.

Comment: Yup. I grew up with this exact model.